# Unity3d Sandboxed Game Center on MacOSX

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, sandbox, game-center

For uncertain reasons the game is not recognized by game center.
If the application GameCenter user is logged in, when you try to log in to the game GameCenter on start, it displays

> This Game is not recognized by Game Center.

If the user is not logged in, in the game the login window appears, but you can not log in; the log shows:

> Failed to authenticate local user The operation could not be completed because the program is not recognized by Game Center.

If Sandboxing enabled (sandbox `<Game>.entitlements` exist), game does not display anything but writes the following to Player.log:

> Failed to authenticate local user Couldn’t communicate with a helper application.

In all cases, if you call the authentication after the game starts, then it writtes to the log that the authentication performed, but Unity social variables contain: `Social.localUser.userName == "Uninitialized"`, `Social.localUser.id == 0`. And when you call the achievements / leader board interfaces, they are displayed with no content, and the log shows:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
>      (
>          `<NSLayoutConstraint:0xfda3ea0 >H:[GKPanelCloseButton]-(NSSpace(8))-[GKPanelCloseButton]   (Names: GKPanelCloseButton:0x3281910 )>`
>      )
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
>      `<NSLayoutConstraint:0xfda3ea0 H:[GKPanelCloseButton]-(NSSpace(8))-[GKPanelCloseButton]   (Names: GKPanelCloseButton:0x3281910 )>`
>
> Set the `NSUserDefault` `NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints` to `YES` to have `-[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:]` automatically called when this happens.
>   And/or, break on `objc_exception_throw` to catch this in the debugger.

If you go to the application GameCenter, there appears that you are logged into the game, but it is under iOS, and it has no content - no icons, no achievements.

Google is silent. Need Your help, how to solve this problem.

Thanks, Ignat

Answer (score 1):

A simple info from Prime[31] website:

> iOS Note: to use the sandbox environment for testing you must **first
>   open the Apple GameCenter.app and log out**. Once logged out, you must
>   be using a debug build in Xcode to access the sandbox. **Release
>   builds will not use the sandbox servers** so be sure to use debug
>   builds when testing.

Source: http://prime31.com/docs#iosGameCenter